# How to query multiple node(id: $id) efficiently in one round trip in Relay?

Tags: relayjs, relay

I have multiple node ids that I want to query with Relay.

What is the best way to fetch nodes data in one round trip and cached properly based on ids?

each node is of the same type and will have the same data structure and query like the following.

```
node(id: $id) {
  id
  ...on Person {
    name
  }
}
```

I just need to run the above query with multiple `$id`s.

Comment: how does your schema look like?